# Nested/conditional chained API calls in React Query?

Tags: react-query, tanstack, tanstackreact-query

We need a function that may call an API or the other, and based on the result, call yet another API.

Let me give a simplified example. We're trying to do something like this

```
function getCarDetails(car: CarSummary): UseQueryResult<CarDetails> {
  if(car.make === 'honda') {
    const hondaResponse = useHondaData(car);

    if(hondaResponse.isError)
      return hondaResponse;
    
    return useCarDetailsData(
      {x: hondaResponse.data?.y},
      {enabled: !!hondaResponse.data}
    );
  }
  else if(car.make === 'tesla') {
    const teslaResponse = useTeslaData(car);

    if(teslaResponse.isError)
      return teslaResponse;
    
    return useCarDetailsData(
      {x: teslaResponse.data?.y},
      {enabled: !!teslaResponse.data}
    );
  }
  else {
    return useCarDetailsData(
      {x: 'generic'},
      {enabled: true}
    );
  }
}
```

The above code would be ideal, if only hooks can be called from inside `if`s.

But as hooks can only be called from the top level, what is the best way to achieve the above (i.e. nested/conditional chained API calls using React Query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding an `enabled` flag to `useHondaData` and `useTeslaData` we can do like below.

Here we always call the hooks, but disable the ones that are not neeeded. Before `return` we check if the first call produced an error, in that case we return that first response, otherwise we return the response from `useCarDetails`.

```js
function getCarDetails(car: CarSummary): UseQueryResult<CarDetails> {
  // always call the hooks but disable the ones not needed with an `enabled` flag
  const hondaResponse = useHondaData(car, { enabled: car.make === 'honda' });
  const teslaResponse = useTeslaData(car, { enabled: car.make === 'tesla' });

  // ignore the types here
  let response: ReturnType<typeof useHondaData> | ReturnType<typeof useTeslaData> | undefined 
  let x: NonNullable<ReturnType<typeof useHondaData>['data']>['y'] | NonNullable<ReturnType<typeof useTeslaData>['data']>['y'] | undefined 
  if (car.make === 'honda' || car.make === 'tesla') {
    // save the appropriate response for later use
    response = car.make === 'honda' ? hondaResponse : teslaResponse
    x = response.data?.y
  } else {
    x = 'generic'
  }
 
  // always call this hook
  const details = useCarDetailsData(
    { x },
    // disable it if we don't have the data we need (x), or if we have an error
    { enabled: !!x && !response?.isError }
  );

  // if we have an error, return the first response, otherwise return the details
  return response.isError ? response : details
}
```

Note that the approach as described in your question would have `getCarDetails` return the output of `useCarDetails` while `useHondaData` or `useTeslaData` are loading, but when one of those fails, it would return the output of `useHondaData` or `useTeslaData`. This might cause confusion and issues. It would be better if we returned a custom object from `getCarDetails`.

E.g. (depending on the needs)

```js
return {
  data: details.data,
  error: response.error ?? details.error,
  isLoading: response.isLoading || details.isLoading
}
```

Also note that since `getCarDetails` uses hooks, it is itself a hook and it's name should start with `use`.